# How to restrict call to inherited public function

Tags: security, inheritance

I'm using OpenZeppelin library for my project and I need to override some functions for business logic. But my concern is with given example,

```
// contract from library
contract A {
    function something_1() public { ... }
    function something_2() public { ... }
}

// contract made my me
contract B is A {
    function something_1() public  { ... }
    function something_2() private { ... }
}
```

outside contract A and B, is it possible for client,

1. to call function `something_1` from contract A?
2. to call function `somethong_2` from contract A?

What I'm trying to achieve is

1. to restrict clients to call `something_1` from contract A so clients can only call `something_1` from contract B
2. to permanently restrict clients calling function `something_2` from contract A and B,

Comment: In the code you shared, there's no inheritance. And how can the client call the function from contract B if you've made it `private`?

Comment: @smarx sorry, I fixed my question

Comment: You can't override a `public` function with a `private` one. This is a compile-time error. (Your code won't compile.)

Comment: @smarx yeah I just checked and it gives error you referred... that asides, then is it possible Q1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the visibility of an overridden function like that. The Solidity language doesn't allow it, so you'll have a compile-time error.

In my opinion, the best thing to do is just mark `something_2` in contract `A` as `internal` or `private`. But if you insist on not touching contract `A`, you can override in `B` and just `revert` the transaction:

```
contract B {
    function something_2() public {
        revert("Not allowed.");
    }
}
```

For your other question, if you deploy contract `B` and someone calls `something_1()`, they'll get the implementation from contract `B`. Of course, that implementation may call into the `super` implementation from contract `A`, but that's entirely up to you.

Comment: thanks, I just wanted to know if an abuser can jump into overriden function that will critically break business logic. In this case, the abusing cannot happen right?

Comment: Not if the Solidity compiler is doing what it's supposed to.